# Upload Python list to sqlitedb

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having some trouble uploading lists to my SQLite db. I would love to be able to upload two lists into my table at once, but for the purposes of this question, I have created a table with one text field called 'names'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
names = ['Jim', 'Grace', 'Francine', 'George',]

For i in names:
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO mytable values(?)', i)
    conn.commit()
```

Instead of this being uploaded to my table:

```
Jim
Grace
Francine
George
```

I get:

```
J
i
m
F
r
a
n
c
etc etc
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but when I run:

```
For i in names:
   print(i)
```

I get the correct output:

```
Jim 
Grace
Francine
George
```

Am I correct in assuming I have to iterate over the list in order to upload the entire thing to my sqlitedb? It's been a couple of months since I touched python, so maybe I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated!

Also, if you need more information, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the statement that includes the `INSERT`:

- You're not executing 'many'.
- The stuff you're inserting needs to be in a list.

---

```
c.execute('insert into mytable values(?)', [i])
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying the executemany after many failed attempts using execute. I completely overlooked inserting `i` as a list.

Comment: I know all about attempts like that, trust me. Anyway, you're welcome.